# C++ File IO persistent temporary file with tmpnam

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to create a couple of temporary files to write and read from, and then have destroyed when the program is complete. I have seen `tmpfile`, which would be great, but I would like to know the name of that file as well. I've read the docs for `ofstream` but I don't think I'm implementing things right.  What I'm trying to do:

1. Create a class that has two member variables that are type `char xFile[64]` and `char yFile[64]`.
2. In the constructor I put: `std::tmpnam(xFile); std::tmpnam(yFile)`. This assigns a c string like `/y3s3` into xFile.
3. I use a method to open the file and add a string.
4. xFile.good() evaluates as false every time.

On point #3, I wrote something like

```
void filemng::makeXCopy (std::string text) {

    // actually I've tried fsteam and ifstream as well, shot in the dark
    std::ofstream xfile(xFile, std::ofstream::out); 

    if(!xfile.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open xFile.\n";
    }

}
```

Of course, when I run it, I see "Failed to open xFile." I just cannot see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Use mkstemp which is safe.

Comment: It's been a year since I did C++, sorry. Upon using tmpnam, it populates a unique file name. Do I need to use fstream or ofstream or ifstream to create the actual file?

Comment: Yes. But it is better to use mkstemp

Comment: According to the documentation you posted `tmpnam()` needs the array to be size `L_tmpnam` as in `char xFile[L_tmpnam];` (maybe not what's causing the error though).

Comment: mkstemp is safe alternative to tmpnam.

Comment: I'll replace it with `mkstemp`. Will I need to use any alternatives to have Windows (7|8) cooperate as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to do it using mkstemp:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[255] = "/tmp/mytempfile_XXXXXX";
    int fd = mkstemp(name);
    if (fd > 0) {
        printf("Created %s\n", name);
        write(fd, "some dataa\n", strlen("some dataa\n"));
        close(fd);
    } else {
        printf("Failed \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that "xxxxxx" in the string passed to mkstmp will be replaced with some unique string that will make the filename unique in the directory.

Comment: Thank you. Should I use something like `tmpnam` to create the unique part of the file name? For the temporary directory, in Windows, will I need to use one of the win32 API functions to try to find a temporary directory?

Comment: No. As you see the "xxxxxx" part in string /tmp/mytempfile_XXXXXX supplied to mkstemp gets replaced. The prefix part is not touched. So, you may pass also something like "/home/user/abcd/somename_xxxxxx". In this case the file is created in directory /home/user/abcd with a name something like somename_n3VvAE